# How to get distinct count on dynamodb on billion objects?

Tags: key-value, amazon-dynamodb

What is the most efficient way to get a number of how many distinct objects is stored in mine dynamodb?

Such as my objects have ten properties and I want to get a distinct count based on 3 properties.

Comment: Do these properties ever change?  How frequently and quickly do you need to get the count?

Comment: they do change...they are not static log data

Comment: What about frequency and latency of asking for the count?  Is this type of aggregation a common, needs-to-be-fast operation?  Do you need this on real-time data or can you perform it on an archive/copy of the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you need counters it's better to use the AtomicCounters (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithDDItems.html). In your case, DynamoDB doesn't support out of the box keys composed out of 3 attributes, unless you concatenate them, so the option would be to create a redundant table where the key is the concatenation of those 3 attributes and each you manage those objects, also update the AtomicCounter (add, delete, update - not needed actually).

Then you just query the counter, avoiding scans. So, it's space complexity to gain speed of retrieving data.

Comment: thanks mate. Ever think in working in uk. Ping please linkedin.com/in/rifaterdemsahin/

Answer (score 1):

Perform a Scan with the appropriate ScanFilter (in this case, that the three properties are not_null), and use withCount(true) to return only the number of matching records instead of the records themselves.

[See the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelJavaScanning.html) for some example code.

Comment: Note that Scan is probably an inefficient way to handle this, as it's a fairly slow operation relative to other DynamoDB operations.  However, given what you've described, I don't have a better answer.

Comment: i guess this billion search operation is a job for sql not for nosql systems.