# Can I do "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM XXX GROUP BY XXX" and "COUNT(DISTINCT XXX )" in DynamoDB?

Tags: database, group-by, amazon-dynamodb

My goals are as simple as:

1. group my data by an attribute and count how many elements are in each group.
2. count how many distinct values are in a field.

Can I do these 2 things in DynamoDB?

Comment: Aggregate functions are not supported in dynamodb at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) group my data by an attribute and count how many elements are in each group.

GROUP BY function is not supported by DynamoDB at the moment. You need to Scan or Query the table and implement it yourself.

2) Count how many distinct values are in a field
There is no distinct function available in Dynamodb either. However, you can get the scanned count and actual count. Please refer this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html).

[Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892611/how-to-get-distict-count-on-dynamodb-on-billion-objects)

> ScannedCount — the number of items that were queried or scanned,
>   before any filter expression was applied to the results. Count — the
>   number of items that were returned in the response.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm switching to other databases.